# Размещение 2 блоков по краям

Tags: html, css

Стоит задача разместить 2 блока (`.logo` и `.panel`) так, чтобы по одной линии один прижался к правому краю `div.backstage`, а другой к левому. При этом, чтобы ни один из них не выходил за границы главного блока (`div.backstage`).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/**/

.backstage {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(Images/background1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.navigation {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.a1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.panel {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 700px;
  background: #fc3;
}
```

```html
<div class="backstage">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="Images/logo1.png" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <a href="#" class="a1">Главная</a>
      <a href="#" class="a1">Сегменты</a>
      <a href="#" class="a1">Гарантия</a>
      <a href="#" class="a1">О нас</a>
      <a href="#" class="a1">Контакты</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что 2 блок у меня позиционируется относительно первого, а не главного блока. Прошу вас помочь.

Answer (score 3):

Само по себе, свойство `flex` просто указывает, что содержимое блока будет распределено особым образом. А для того, чтобы блок знал, как именно распределять, нужно добавить ещё свойства. Например, `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.backstage {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh; width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  background-color: #686;
  background-image: url(Images/background1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.logo {
  height: 100px; width: 150px;
  background-color: #f88;
}

.panel {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 700px;
  background-color: #fc3;
}

.navigation {
  font: 600 30px/1em serif;
}

.a1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="backstage">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="Images/logo1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <a href="#" class="a1">Главная</a>
      <a href="#" class="a1">Сегменты</a>
      <a href="#" class="a1">Гарантия</a>
      <a href="#" class="a1">О нас</a>
      <a href="#" class="a1">Контакты</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Дополнительный вопрос.. После того как я использовал justify-content я могу добавлять отступы от краев ?

Comment: @РоманКостенко: смотря у каких блоков. Уточните.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте на родительском блоке свойство `justify-content: space-between`. Это разнесёт элементы в противоположные стороны.